# How to safely pass an email address through a query string using javascript/php?

Tags: string, email

I have a form who's data will be submitted to a salesforce.com database via the action parameter

```
<form name="ifsLeadsForm" id="ifsLeads" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="post">
```

Salesforce allows for a return url where the user will be sent after the data is submitted to the database.

```
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="myReturnURL" />
```

I need to pass the value of the "firstName" input and the  "email" input from the form on to the return URL (a php document) so I can $_GET the name and email address and an email can be sent to the user thanking them for submitting their info.

I used the .serialize() function to grab the key/value of the firstName and email inputs and appended them to the return URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#submit').click(function(ev){
    var queryString = $('#first_name, #email').serialize();

    document.ifsLeadsForm.retURL.value = "http://www.myDomain.com/return.php?"+queryString;
    });

</script>
```

My question is -

Is it safe to be passing an email address through a query string like this? If not, what is the safe way?

I appreciate any help.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

With GET request data is visible to everyone in the URL. POST request is a little safer than GET because the parameters are not stored in browser history or in web server logs.

You have to make ajax request and get it on the server side with $_POST.

More info on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp